# How to fix "conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'is turned' to data type int"

Tags: sql-server

I did some changes in my IMOS database and got it working but when my customer tried the same they ended up with an error. When searching from google I think the line needs some CONVERT(...) included but I don't know how to do this. Can somebody help me? The code and error is below.

```
update CAMDLATTROUTPUT
set OUTPUTFLAG = 1
where ATTRTYPE = '10400'
  and ATTRTYPE = 'is turned'
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'is turned' to data type int.

Comment: The error is clearly telling you the problem here `'is turned'` is not an `int`, and your using it as a comparison against the column `ATTRTYPE`; which I suspect is an` int`. Sometimes reading the error message is the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Okei, I know i sound stupid, but i haven't learned anything about SQL. Would you just correct the line so that my code works? Also can you say why in my database this code above worked but on other one it didn't? :)

Comment: I *could* correct the line, but a `int` will never have the value of `'is turned'`, so it your query would never return any rows. I can't help you solve the real problem, as I don't know what it is. You know your database better than anyone, so I ask, why *are* you trying to see what integers have the (string) value of `'is turned'`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: `ATTRTYPE` can never ever have 2 different values at the same time. So checking on `= '10400' and = 'is turned'` makes no sense and will always return 0 records. Regardless of the error and regardless of the content of this table

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ATTRTYPE column is defined as int, therefore the first part of your statement should be

```
UPDATE CAMDLATTROUTPUT
SET OUTPUTFLAG = 1
WHERE ATTRTYPE = 10400
```

(without the single quotes).

What leaves me confused is the line

```
AND ATTRTYPE = 'is turned'
```

which can't be an integer of any kind. Therefore I suspect that this could be the foreign key to another table that contains a record with an ID and the text "is turned". In this case you would need a join.

On the other hand: A single column of a record can never ever be as well 10400 AND 'is turned' at the same time. Therefore, even if ATTRTYPE would be a string and you would not get a syntax error, the number of rows affected by that query will always be 0.

Comment: Thanks for any help you guys gave. i found out that my customer made a mistake in code. Last should not be ATTRTYPE = 'is turned' but should be ATTRIBUTE = 'is turned'.So I am very sorry for wasting your valuable time :). But the right code worked for me but not for customer. When they executed that line they got error saying: Invalid object name 'CAMDLATTROUTPUT'. But it's almost like copy-paste, maybe you could say why it would give that error?

Comment: That error means that table `CAMDLATTROUTPUT`  does not exists. Maybe he is working on a wrong database ? Or a wrong version of it ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you can't make any changes into that if you don't have it to open it, can you?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, changed line -

update CAMDLATTROUTPUT set OUTPUTFLAG=1 where ATTRTYPE='10400' and ATTRIBUTE = 'is turned'

into

update [imos].[dbo].[CAMDLATTROUTPUT] set OUTPUTFLAG=1 where ATTRTYPE='10400' and ATTRIBUTE = 'is turned'

Don't know why first one is not working for everyone but I hope that atleast someone will find a solution for his problem from here :)